# How can I auto-logged a user inside a Sharepoint Web Part?

Tags: typescript, azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory

[image]

I have a website "Play web". When I want to access into this site I have to login previously with user/pass. An authtentication module, handle this info and starts a communication with an Azure AD. If the user is validated properly using a callback the control is returned to the Play Web with the user logged. All these steps works fine.

Where is the problem?. One of our clients wants to embed this "Play web" inside his Sharepoint but he doesn't want relogin. He needs to use the Sharepoint context to autologged the user into the website.

Is there any way to do this?,  Should have I setup something in Azure AD: Proxy, Function?

I'm stuck with this.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I have solve the problem using Msal library:

```
import {UserAgentApplication} from "msal";

const config = {
auth: {
clientId: "client-id",
 authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id"
 }
};

const myMSALObj = new UserAgentApplication(config);

let accessTokenRequest = {
scopes: ["user.read"],
 loginHint: this.context.pageContext.user.loginName,
 extraQueryParameters: {domain_hint: 'organizations'}    
}     

myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest).then(
function(accessTokenResponse) {
// Acquire token silent success
 // call API with token
 let accessToken = accessTokenResponse.accessToken;
 let scopes = accessTokenResponse.scopes;
 }).catch(function (error) {
//Acquire token silent failure, and send an interactive request
 console.log(error);
 if (error.errorMessage.indexOf("interaction_required") !== -1) {
myMSALObj.acquireTokenRedirect(accessTokenRequest);
  }
});
```